# Heaviside function as a càdlàg adapted process of finite variation

Tags: stochastic-processes

As written in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function), the Dirac delta function is the derivative of the Heaviside function
$${\displaystyle \delta (x)={\frac {d}{dx}}H(x)}$$
Hence the Heaviside function can be considered to be the integral of the Dirac delta function$$
{\displaystyle H(x):=\int _{-\infty }^{x}\delta (s)\,ds}$$
In this context, the Heaviside function is the cumulative distribution function of a random variable which is almost surely $0$.

I would like to show that the Heaviside function is a càdlàg adapted process of finite variation. Could you please help me?

Comment: Using the definition of [variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation#Total_variation_for_functions_of_one_real_variable) can you show directly that the variation of $H$ is zero on every interval in $(-\infty,0)$ and one on every larger interval ? In other words: the variation of $H$ is $H$ itself. See also [this](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Function_of_bounded_variation#Jump_functions).

Comment: adapted to what?

Comment: It will be adapted to every filtration since it is a deterministic function. 
The cadlag and finite variation property can easily be seen by directly checking "the" defnition of both.
For this, it would be better to simply think of H as $H(x) = 0$ for $x \leq 0$ and $H(x) = 1$ for $x > 0$.

Comment: Thank you, your comments answer my question!